# objective C Programmatically Deleting account from Keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am saving my data into Keychain using SSkeychain class, but when i try to iterate through the accounts the application crashes in the third item from list, where acct = <5f70666f>;

I am trying to delete that particular account but i am not be able to delete it . I tried deleting all the keychain data associated to app, but still i am facing the issue

```
SSKeychainQuery *query = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
BOOL isMatchPasscode=FALSE;
NSArray *accounts = [query fetchAll:nil];
for (id account in accounts){
    if([[account 
    valueForKey:@"acct"]isEqualToString:constKeychainAccountTitle ] )
    {
    }
}

LOG FOR ACCOUNTS
acct = "fc_uuidForDevice";
agrp = "99P5TJ23MZ.com.view.Street.dev";
cdat = "2017-03-07 08:53:17 +0000";
mdat = "2017-03-07 09:45:32 +0000";
musr = <>;
pdmn = ck;
svce = "com.view.Str.dev";
sync = 0;
tomb = 0;
},
{
acct = "fc_uuidsOfUserDevices";
agrp = "99P5TJ23MZ.view.Street.dev";
cdat = "2017-03-07 08:53:17 +0000";
mdat = "2017-03-07 09:45:32 +0000";
musr = <>;
pdmn = ck;
svce = "com.view.Street.dev";
sync = 1;
tomb = 0;
},
{
acct = <5f70666f>;
agrp = "99P5TJ23MZ.view.Street.dev";
cdat = "2017-03-07 08:53:20 +0000";
gena = <5f70666f>;
mdat = "2017-03-07 08:53:20 +0000";
musr = <>;
pdmn = dku;
svce = "com.view.Street.dev";
sync = 0;
tomb = 0;
}
)
```

Comment: What is the crash message and stack trace?

Comment: -[__NSCFData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740abcb0

Comment: So your code assumes that it is getting a string from keychain, but in this case it retrieved NSData and you then tried to perform a string comparison on it.   You should change your code to use `isKindOfClass` to check you have a string before performing string operations

Comment: i am trying to compare nsdata with respect to string, thats the cause of crash. 
i have two version of my app, development and production, the devices which i use test the development build crashes the application from the app store and i am not able to run the apps store version on those devices

Comment: You can't perform a string comparison on NSData. You can initialise a string from NSData.

Answer (score 2):

> -[__NSCFData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740abcb0
>
> i am trying to compare nsdata with respect to string, thats the cause of crash.

Try something like this:

```
id acctObject = [account valueForKey:@"acct"];
NSString *acctString = ([acctObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) ? (NSString *)acctObject : ([acctObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) ? [[NSString alloc] initWithData:acctObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] : nil;

if (acctString && [acctString isEqualToString:constKeychainAccountTitle]) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have already implemented this code in my latest version and its not crashing any more. The issue is in order to save data into device securely i am using keychain in the development version, but the build which i have already uploaded to app store, is crashing. It doesnt crash on the device that has been not used to test development version its only crashed on those device which have/has development build tested